# Integer overflow detection C# for Add

Tags: c#

It's easy to get C# to throw an exception on an integer overflow. However, that's not what I'm looking for. I want to detect the overflow so I can continue the calculation in the high order. I'm building a sort of big int implementation.

I could catch the overflow exception, but that's not great for performance. Not to mention that it's conceptually incorrect.

Any idea how to check for overflow without exceptions?

Comment: Please add an example of code with potential overflow.

Comment: Do you know that there's a `BigInteger` class in C#, or are you doing this just for practice?

Comment: I assume the overflow is with a Single(), Double(), or Float() object when you are using Parse() or when you are performing a math operation.  If the error is occurring due to Parse than use ParseExact().  If it is a math operations, it is usually caused by denominator of a division being very small (or zero).  So check denominator before dividing.

Comment: I spent some time thinking about this as the question was an interesting bit of academics to ponder. My conclusion however is that you'd end up needing to write your own overflow detection in all operations that something like checked already does. I would expect any good implementation to be equally slow as what you're wanting to avoid, but with more bugs and gotchas. Without knowing the exact problem you're trying to solve, I would suggest the approach you're trying to avoid.

Comment: I'm with Atoms. I think it's not possible to know if overflow may happen before doing a possible overflow method.

Comment: @Rob I think I will probably use the BigInteger class. I didn't realize it existed, though I should have expected it.

Comment: Not overflow, the term is "carry".  You do this just the way you learned to do it in elementary school.  6 + 3 = 9, no carry, 6 + 4 = 10, you carry the 1 to the next column.  Exactly how you do it greatly depends on the way you represent digits in the number.  With the obvious requirement that you need to be able to detect a carry and avoid overflow.  One byte for one digit trivially gets the job done, but is not the most efficient way to store the digits or the most efficient way to calculate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are seeking for a carry behavior, other answers/comments cover that pretty well. However, I find the original question to be an interesting brain puzzle (although not practically useful), specifically what is the best performance pure C# way to detect 2 signed integers add overflow. Ideally it would generate a minimum IL instructions with no branches. Here is the best I ended up - one with bool flag (true when overflow, false otherwise) and another with int "bit" (1 when overflow, 0 otherwise). Both satisfy the above criteria, "bit" version has few less IL instructions. Enjoy:-)

```
static int Add(int a, int b, out bool overflowFlag)
{
    unchecked
    {
        int c = a + b;
        overflowFlag = ((a ^ b) >= 0) & ((a ^ c) < 0);
        return c;
    }
}
static int Add(int a, int b, out int overflowBit)
{
    unchecked
    {
        int c = a + b;
        overflowBit = (int)((uint)((a ^ c) & ~(a ^ b)) >> 31);
        return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: Though I'm probably not going to use this (BigInteger serves my purpose), it does answer the question and in a pretty cool way. The downside is that you probably can't do something similar for Multiplication.

Comment: absolutely - that's why I mentioned it's usefulness at the beginning. but glad that you liked it:-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement addition and subtraction with carry, I really recommend using `uint` instead of `int`! Cast both values to `ulong` before doing the calculation:

```
//Adds a and b
uint[] a = ... , b = ... ;//input
ulong carry=0
for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
{
    carry += (ulong)a[i] + (ulong)b[i];
    uint result = (uint)carry;
    carry >>= 32;//divide by 2^32
    //TODO: store result
}
//TODO: process remaining carry
```

I had problems with sign extension, when i first implemnted something like this, hence the unsigned types everywhere.

Comment: What kind of problems did you have with the sign extension?